# Gtk-Message: Failed to load module

Tags: python, pyqt5

Я использую PyQt5. При запуске приложения выводит эту ошибку:

```
Gtk-Message: 22:09:21.335: Failed to load module "window-decorations-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 22:09:21.335: Failed to load module "colorreload-gtk-module"
```

Использую Debian Linux. Читал что бы это исправить надо:

```
apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

но это мне не помогло. Ошибка выходит при использовании:

```
app = QApplication([])
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: ошибка появляется сразу при использовании qapplication